# How to deploy react, next js + express js app to netlify?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, next.js, netlify

I am trying to deploy my app to netlify which is created by using react, next js, and express js.

There is no error in netlify console Despite this, site is not being live.

[image]

Here are my package.json scripts.

[image]

Here are my variable environments on netlify.
[image]

Here are my build settings to netlify.
[image]

Please can anyone tell me where I am making mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

```js
npm run build
```

then drag and drop this build folder but netlify doesnt support server i think firebase is the best option or herokuu too

Comment: Hi arsian, thank you for your valuable reply, Above you can see that I am running the command "yarn run deploy" In yarn run deploy I am hitting two commands. First one is "yarn run build" and second one is yarn run start. Also here one more point  I am using next js So next js does not create build folder It creates .next folder.